# Output of pointer to caller SAL error

Tags: c++, c, pointers, sal

I am trying to add [SAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032.aspx)to my code... i worked according msdn and found bug in msdn examples, don't know how to deal with it.

Here litle changed example "Output of pointer to caller (Example: The Outptr Annotation)" from  [Understanding SAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh916383.aspx)

> Outptr is used to annotate a parameter that's intended to return a
>   pointer. The parameter itself should not be NULL, and the called
>   function returns a non-NULL pointer in it and that pointer points to
>   initialized data.

My code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "assert.h"

void GoodOutPtrCallee(_Outptr_ int **pInt)
{
    int *pInt2 = new int;

    if (*pInt != NULL)
    {
        *pInt2 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        *pInt2 = 2;
    }

    *pInt = pInt2;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int* nullValue = NULL;
    GoodOutPtrCallee(&nullValue); 
    assert(*nullValue == 2);

    int someValue = 22;
    int* someValuePtr = &someValue;
    GoodOutPtrCallee(&someValuePtr); 
    assert(*someValuePtr == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

If i compile it in VS2013 with code alalysys enabled i got [C6001: using uninitialized memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C6001)&rd=true)

for

```
if (*pInt != NULL)
```

row.

What is worng here in my annotation and how can i fix it?

Comment: If you want bad code like this to pass an analysis then you have to *remove* the SAL annotation.  Surely that isn't your intention.

Comment: @HansPassant that is demo code to find how SAL works... not ideal.. but what is so-so bad in such approach?

Comment: SAL is not well documented. I find the VC++ header, matching my function prototype, and see how it is annotated. As of now, I cannot collect such function (`int**`).

Comment: I'd simply say the compiler tells us that what `pInt` is pointing is being read although `pInt` is been annotated to "only" return something, which implies it is being written only.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're reading from the value passed through the pointer parameter `pInt` you can't use `_Outptr_` , as this describes a parameter that's only used as an output, not also as an input. Use `_Inout_` instead.

You might want to reconsider using SAL. It's very poorly documented, and as a result I can't say with any certainty that `_Inout_` is actually the best annotation to use here. All I know for sure is that it's best match I could find based on Microsoft's vague descriptions, and it gets rid of the warning. Of course so would not using an annotation.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT*: I was confused by similar variable names, `pInt` and `pInt2`.
You're probably should mark `pInt` as input and output, not just as output, because you're reading it's value to check whether it is `NULL`

Comment: Kirill, i am trying to check whether pointer on pointer is pointed on value or null..please see my updated code.

Comment: Annotation is mostly correct. Code is for sure correct.

Comment: Oh, I see, my fault. Looks like annotation `_Outptr_` is insufficient: if `pInt` is used only as output (as annotation says), then why you tread it as input (by checking it's value for `NULL`)?